# Changing default permanent USERS tablespace to bigfile

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, users, tablespaces

I'm trying to build an oracle database server but it's setting up the users tablespace as a smallfile.   How can I either install brand new database with users being bigfile or changing the existing USERS tablespace to bigfile?

Answer (score 0):

**Change existing:**

```
SQL> create bigfile tablespace users2 datafile '/oradata/ORCL2/users.dbf' size 100M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> alter database default tablespace users2;

Database altered.
```

**Create new one:**

DBCA allows you to choose bigfile tablespace for a Custom Database:

[image]

A "General Purpose" or "Data Warehouse" database is actually a pre-created database, there you do not have this option.

Or you can specify bigfile when creating a database with the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.